# How to Validate Business Rule in Service or Repo

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, repository

I am hoping to create a base Entity Class that includes a validation rule that checks if a field called "Title" is unique (which of course requires a db scan). I want the inherited models to run the validation rule in the repo (or service) layer and send a ValidationResult to the (MVC) client-layer.

The problem is one of inheritance.

```
public interface IUniqueTitle
{
    int Id { get; set; }  
    string Title { get; set; }  
    // This is a "multi-client, one database" solution.  
    // Data is isolated using SiteId  
    int SiteId { get; set; }  

}

// Models such as "MemberClub" and "Assessment" will inherit from this
public class EntityUniqueTitle : IUniqueTitle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

// This class will be used in production
public class MemberClub : EntityUniqueTitle
{

}
```

I wrote an extension method that to check to see if the Title field is unique based on the SiteId

```
public static bool IsUniqueTitle<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, T currentEntity) where T : IUniqueTitle  
{  
    return items.Where(  
    item => item.Id != currentEntity.Id // INCASE UPDATING OBJECT  
    & item.SiteId == currentEntity.SiteId  
    & item.Title == currentEntity.Title)  
    .Count() == 0;  
}
```

Here is where I get stuck. Where should I put the validation?

I can put in the Repo but can't figure out how to fire the ValidationResult upon Save

```
public class RepoUniqueTitle<T> : IRepoUniqueTitle<T> where T : EntityUniqueTitle, new()  
{
        protected readonly DbContext c;  
        public Repo(IDbContextFactory f) { c = f.GetContext(); }

        public void Insert(T o)
        {

            if (!c.Set<T>().IsUniqueTitle(o))
            {
                // ***********************
                // PROBLEM HERE, HOW DO I STOP AND SEND A VALIDATIONRESULT TO THE CLIENT?
                // IF POSSIBLE, AUOTMATIC WHEN MODEL.ISVALID IS CALLED

                // code from base repo class for reference
                // if (o is IUniqueTitleForSite)
                //   IoC.Resolve<IRepoUniqueTitle<T>>().Validate(o);

            }
            else
                c.Set<T>().Add(o);
        }

    }
```

I am hoping there is a validation solution that:

- Models can inherit from a base Entity
- Can make db calls to the inherited entity's collection
- Works with ValidationResult so it can be cleanly integrated into MVC Tier
- Called during Model.isValid if possible

Note: I am using [ProDinner](http://prodinner.codeplex.com/) as a basis for an "n-tier code-first EF mvc/wf" solution.

Sorry, a lot of this is new to me. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is where I think something like the Csla.Net framework fits; you define your business objects and part of that is defining the business rules; EF (or whatever data access you implement) need not be involved.

Answer (score 1):

If you have separate business logic layer you should place the validation to that layer. Otherwise why to have that layer if you don't use it to execute business rules?

Anyway unique check is tricky because there is a delay between your query and actual saving of data and another thread can insert the item with the same title during that delay. You should place unique index on `Title` and `SiteId` to enforce uniqueness in the database. In such case former problem will result in the exception which you must handle somehow but it is probably better then data duplicity.

Comment: Unfortunately, the unique index won't work because there are a few other variables in the validation rule that I have left out for readability. (ie, "IsDeleted")

Comment: I agree the rule should exist in the business logic layer, but how do I do it so it will work with all the inherited Entities (ie "MemberClubs") and return a ValidationResult to the client. Thanks!!!